# How to generate a <select> list in Laravel without value attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In order for my [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) widgets to work properly, I need the very first option to have no value attribute and no text.  Having no text is not difficult with Laravel, of course, but having no value attribute seems to be impossible.  How can I make Laravel generate select lists without value attributes—at least for some of the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop over the array/data object yourself and store the information in your own format.  Using Form::select() will generate this with the appropriate values already, simply replace with your own code to loop over them without the value attribute.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was afraid of.  Seems like a huge oversight in the design of `Form::select`.  Oh well.

Comment: From personal experience I have yet to generate a select that requires I don't have the value attribute filled in though :)

Comment: In most cases the text is the same as the value you want passed to the server.  The HTML spec handles this nicely: if there's no value attribute, the text is used.

Comment: I've yet to see a single case in almost twenty years of web development where array indices (0,1,2, etc, not associative array keys) would be useful as values to pass to a server.